# nginx not restarting after changing port

Tags: webserver, nginx

I have tried to change the port in which nginx listens for from 80 to 6000. However I get this when I try to restart it.

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:6000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:6000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:6000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:6000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:6000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

This is my sites-enabled setup.

```
server {
    listen   6000; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/mywebsite.co/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name mywebsite.co www.website.co;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }
}
```

I have a feeling the `0.0.0.0:6000` should be the ip address in which the server is held on e.g `192.168.1.3:6000` however I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `#listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6`

To:
`listen [::]:6000 ipv6only=on default_server`;

If that doesn't work, you could `netstat -natp | grep 6000` to see more info.

Comment: Thanks `netstat -natp | grep 6000` helped. I found I was using another service with this port.

Answer (score 1):

TCP port 6000 is the port normally used by the X Window system.  If you're on a UNIX-ish system that's not a Mac and you're using a GUI, then port 6000 is most likely already in use by the X server running on the local machine.  That's why nginx is failing to bind to it.

Comment: Yeah I found I was using another service with that port. Issue Resolved, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to find out whats running on a well known port (ie tcp/6000), you could do something like, as root:

> for i in $(grep [WELLKNOWNPORT] /etc/services|awk '{print $1}'); do lsof|grep $i; done